# Calling a function that's inside another function from a function

Tags: python

To be more specific, I want to call the function get_hours_worked from inside
calc_gross_pay. I realize that another way to do this is to just pass arguments into calc_gross_pay, but I was wondering if what I was trying to do is possible. I have a feeling it's not. Thanks for any help.

```
def main():
#
    print("This employee's gross pay for two weeks is:",calc_gross_pay())


def get_input():

    def get_hours_worked():
        #get_hours_worked
        x = float(input("How many hours worked in this two week period?     "))
        return x

    def get_hourly_rate():
        #get_hourly_rate()

        y = float(input("What is the hourly pay rate for this employee? "))
        return y

def calc_gross_pay():
    #
    gross = get_input(get_hours_worked) * get_input(get_hourly_rate)
    return gross

main()
```

Comment: Any specific reason for declaring functions inside a function ?

Comment: No, the names `get_hours_worked` and `get_hourly_rate` are local to `get_input`. If you want to access those functions outside `get_input` you need to return them. But why do you want to define those functions inside `get_input` anyway?

Comment: Why do you want to call `get_input(get_hours_worked)` when calling simply `get_hours_worked()` gets the work done? In your example `get_input` is doing nothing.

Comment: I'm trying to program this from this chart https://imgur.com/a/smZCv

I understand how variables are local to the function and cannot be accessed from outside the function. From what you said, the same is true for functions inside a function. My logic was, that by calling the get_input function, it would ask the user for input. The way the hierarchy chart was made, I assumed get_hours_worked was a function under get_input. Thus, if you call get_input and get_hours_worked , you could pass that value to calc_gross_pay .

Comment: You could do it by having `get_input` return the functions you want to call, basically creating a closure, then save those returned functions to call later, but that's a pretty convoluted way to export a function.

Comment: In the chart image it is clearly said that _the `get-input` function *calls* other two functions_. But you are not calling them from `get_input`.

Comment: I see. I am supposed to call get_hours_worked within get_input. Then, I return that value? 

Ex:
    def get_input():
        def get_hours_worked():
            x = float(input("Hrs worked? :))
            return x
         y = get_hours_worked

Comment: No, you should call `get_input` within `get_hours_worked `, as shown in my answer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a reorganized version of your code. Rather than defining `get_hours_worked` and `get_hourly_rate` inside `get_input` we define them as separate functions that call `get_input`.

```
def get_input(prompt):
    return float(input(prompt))

def get_hours_worked():
    return get_input("How many hours worked in this two week period? ")

def get_hourly_rate():
    return get_input("What is the hourly pay rate for this employee? ")

def calc_gross_pay():
    return get_hours_worked() * get_hourly_rate()

def main():
    print("This employee's gross pay for two weeks is:", calc_gross_pay())

main()
```

**demo**

```
How many hours worked in this two week period? 50
What is the hourly pay rate for this employee? 20.00
This employee's gross pay for two weeks is: 1000.0
```

Comment: Thank you. This makes more sense. I am misunderstanding the hierarchy chart in my text.

Answer (score 0):

As [PM 2Ring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46860732/7550472) pointed out, its better to change the hierarchy itself. But in case you want the same still, proceed as follows :

```
def get_input():

    def get_hours_worked():
        x = float(input("How many hours worked in this two week period?     "))
        return x

    def get_hourly_rate():
        y = float(input("What is the hourly pay rate for this employee? "))
        return y

    return get_hours_worked, get_hourly_rate                         # IMP

def calc_gross_pay():
    call_worked, call_rate = get_input()                             # get the functions
    gross = call_worked() * call_rate()                              # call them
    return gross     


def main():
    print("This employee's gross pay for two weeks is:",calc_gross_pay())

    #How many hours worked in this two week period?  3
    #What is the hourly pay rate for this employee?  4
    #This employee's gross pay for two weeks is: 12.0

main()
```

Comment: Oh wow this will work? So when you say call_worked, do you mean get_hours_worked? I'm just making sure "call" isn't a keyword. Then you use the assignment operator with get_input() . Which is odd. Does the "=" still behave as an assignment operator?

Edit: Now that I've taken a closer looks, it seems that call_worked acts a local variable. Since there are two variables, call_worked and call_rate, they receive the returned values from get_input. I would guess they receive the returned date in the order it was returned?

Comment: Yes, your second guess (edit part) was up to the point. The return value from `get_input` are the two functions , which is being assigned to the two variables `call_worked` and `call_rate`. Using which we access the functions.